# Struct in C with (.) or → operator

Tags: c, struct, operator-keyword

Guys I'm a little confused with the -> operator in C, can someone explain to me how it works and how it can be used, and the main diference between dot . operator and -> operator, what is the name of this operator -> ?

P.S. I need very much to understand this , to complete an exercise , please explain me or gibe me, pdf , video, tutorial or something to help me, thanks!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

struct dashboard{
    char name[20];
    int idade;      
};

struct dashboard user;

char* n = strcpy(user.name, "anyname");
user.idade = 10;  

printf("Name is: %s and age is: %d", n, user.idade); 

return 0;}
```

how can I implement this same structure with the -> ?

The answer to my question with help of stackoverflow members.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

struct dashboard{
    char name[20];
    int idade;      
};

struct dashboard *user, u;

//Referencing pointer to memory address of u 
user = &u;  

char* n = strcpy(user->name, "anyname");
user->idade = 10;  

printf("Name is: %s, Age is: %d", n, user->idade); 

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The `->` operator is sort of lacking a name.  C++ calls it `operator->`, but wikipedia calls it the "Structure dereference" amongst other things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot picks members of structures. The arrow dereferences pointers to structures and then picks a member.

```
struct dashboard user, *up = &user;

. . . user.name . . .
. . . up->name . . .
```

are equivalent (assuming up still points to user).

Comment: so, this code is correct? 
 
 struct dashboard{
  char name[20];
  int idade;  
 };
       
    struct dashboard *user;
  
 user->idade;  
 user->name;

Comment: Um, no, because you don't make "user" point to anything before trying to dereference it. You still need to actually allocate memory for a structure.

Answer (score 3):

Point is used for structure instance (object), and -> is when you access the structure with pointer. E.g. `obj.member` and `ptr_obj->member`.

Answer (score 1):

`structure.field` is the field on the structure, that simple. `structure->field` is  equivalent to `(*structure).field`. `->` its used when you want to access the field of a structure pointed by a pointer you have. imagine you have this structure:

```
 typedef struct example{
   int field1;
   int field2;
 } ExStructure;
```

ans this variables:

```
ExStructure a, *b;
```

you have an structure and a pointer to an structure. if you want to access to the field one of the first structure, you simply do `X=a.field1`. But the second one is a pointer to an structure so to access the field1 of that structure you need to do `X=(*b).field1`, and that's equivalent to `X=b->field1`. So `->` makes the code simpler to read.

Comment: I follow your example, but the compiler not work, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong , but it seems to me you are missing some additional explanation! Because when i tried to access field1 with the pointer *b the IDE freezes.

Comment: @superuser I highly doubt the IDE freezes.

Comment: well, that example was just to show you the difference. when you try to run it as a program, it probably freezes (you are working in windows i guess) because it gives a segmentation fault error. you have to allocate memory to `*b` using malloc: `b=malloc (sizeof (ExStructure) );` . remember that you are declaring the pointer to an struct (*b), but it isn't pointing at any memory location yet. You could also make b point to a and then try to access the field on b, but if you want them to be two different structures, you will have to use malloc.

Comment: @immibis  Yes is it  freeze, because i not referencing or alocate memory to the pointer, and angel208  you can use another way, referencing pointer to another address to access memory like the Lee Daniel Crocker done, anyway thaks a lot!